# Question about "Dedication" section in thesis

Tags: word-order

Is it correct to dedicate a thesis to my parents and my wife as follows? Can I put their names at the end?

> To my mother and father,
>
> who have blessed me with an admiration of nature.
>
> -- Sara & Michael
>
> To my wife,
>
> whose love and confidence is a constant source of inspiration and
>   encouragement.
>
> -- Rose

My mother's name is Sara, my father's name is Michael, and my wife's name is Rose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be understood, but it matches the form used for split dedications. Say Alice and Bob wrote a paper together, the dedication might be:

> To my husband,
>
> Charles,
>
> who put up with my insanity as this was finished
>
> -- Alice.
>
> To my loving wife,
>
> Eve,
>   and to my mother and father.
>
> -- Bob.

While we wouldn't read your example as saying that, it would look like that form.

I'd recommend:

> To my mother and father,
>
> Sara & Michael,
>
> who have blessed me with an admiration of nature.
>
> And to my wife,
>
> Rose,
>
> whose love and confidence is a constant source of inspiration and
>   encouragement.